# Cypress - Working with div tables - Validating text on each row

Tags: javascript, cypress, ag-grid

I want to check if the first column of each row's text starts with "AA", "BB" or "CC". But I couldn't manage it on div table. I can only select and check the first row (code below). But I also tried with selecting the whole column and tried with using `cy.each` & `cy.wrap` and got errors too.

How can I check the first column for each row's text? (Table has 40-45 rows.)

The table looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Right now I can only check the first row with the code below. How can I check all the rows like this? Is the code below clear to you by the way?

```
cy.get('div[row-index="0"]')
           .eq(1)
           .invoke('text')
           .then(text => {
            const productID = text.trim();
             let correctProductIDPrefix = false;
             ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'].forEach(possibleProductIDPrefix => {
             if (!correctProductIDPrefix) {
               correctProductIDPrefix = productID.startsWith(possibleProductIDPrefix);
             }
         });
         expect(correctProductIDPrefix).to.be.true;
       });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform the same test on all rows

- select all the rows (change `[row-index="0"]` to `[row-index]`)
- use `.each()` to run test on all rows
- sub-select just the column you want, in case some other column also has the prefix and gives you a **false-positive** result
- use `Array.some()` method to check at least one prefix matches

```js
const possibleProductPrefixes = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']     // define once outside test

cy.get('div[row-index]')           // selects every row
  .each($row => {

    const $col = $row.find('[col-id="orderNumber"]')  // pick out the column
    const productId = $col.text().trim()

    const correctProductIDPrefix = possibleProductPrefixes.some(prefix => {
      return productId.startsWith(prefix)
    })

    expect(correctProductIDPrefix).to.be.true;
  });
```

---

Ref [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The **some()** method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.

Comment: For more clarity, you should be able to use  `expect(productId).to.be.oneOf(possibleProductPrefixes)`

Comment: That would take a substring or regex - see `startsWith()` requirement. `expect(productId.subString(0,2)).to.be.oneOf(possibleProductPrefixes)` is possible, maybe a little inflexible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
let prefix = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']
cy.get('.ag-cell-value').each(($ele, index) => {
  expect($ele.text().trim().startsWith(prefix[index])).to.be.true
})
```

Comment: The table has so many columns and rows and when I do;
**"cy.get('.ag-cell-value')"** it selects everything inside the table although I'm getting the first column first. It also selects the column title as well.

---
`
 let prefix = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']
      cy.get('div[col-id="productID"]')
      cy.get('.ag-cell-value').each(($ele, index) => {
        expect($ele.text().trim().startsWith(prefix[index])).to.be.true
`

Comment: Can you send me the html screenshot of the first three elements, that should be enough to figure out

Comment: I've just uploaded the screenshot here; https://ibb.co/M8Rcr5T
Thanks Alapan!